# Inverting a PGM's Color Values Distorts the Image

Tags: c, eclipse, pgm

My goal is to read in a PGM image and produce an image with inverted color values.  But when I put in [this image](http://imageshack.us/a/img62/9575/sy1n.jpg), I get back [this image](http://imageshack.us/a/img10/2323/ablo.jpg).  I'm programming in C, using Eclipse and MinGW GCC on Windows 7 (64-bit).  Why is the image getting so drastically distorted?

```
int complement(PGMImage *img) {
int i, j;

// set up new PGM to copy onto
PGMImage* comImg = (PGMImage*)malloc(sizeof(PGMImage));
(*comImg).width = (*img).width;
(*comImg).height = (*img).height;

// invert each pixel
for(i = 0; i <= (*img).width; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j <= (*img).height; j++) {

        // set inverted value for each new pixel
        (*comImg).data[i][j].red = abs((*img).maxVal - (*img).data[i][j].red);
        (*comImg).data[i][j].green = abs((*img).maxVal - (*img).data[i][j].green);
        (*comImg).data[i][j].blue = abs((*img).maxVal - (*img).data[i][j].blue);
    }
}

// save a copy of the complement image
save("C:\\image_complement.pgm", comImg);
printf("A copy of your image has been saved as \"C:\\image_complement.pgm\"\n\n");
void free(comImg);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you set `maxval` in `comImg`? Otherwise file might receive a garbage value.

Comment: @luserdroog I added that, but I'm getting the same result.

Comment: Googling `PGMImage` I've found different incompatible definitions  [here](http://sun.iwu.edu/~shelley/sie/zoo/journal/research.c.2.html) and [here](https://gist.github.com/hkulekci/2820788). Maybe your problem lies somewhere there. Have you already tried writing back the orginal image?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I would suspect the outer array index of your image to be the line and the inner to be the column. Thus I would expect that `i` should run to `(*img).height` and `j` to `(*img).width`.

Comment: I switched .height and .width, but that just gave me [this image](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/9818/ipys.jpg), which is more or less the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think `<=` should be `<` in both of your loops. With the revised image, from the comments to the other answer, it looks like it's "stepping over the edge" on each row.

---

Um, a `pgm` is a *graymap*, right? What does "red" "green" and "blue" mean?

Comment: That's the way the header file is set up.  I don't really get why it's called a graymap, but PGM files can have full color.

Comment: I'd recommend you try only accessing the "red" values. PGM files cannot have color (at least, not multiple channels like this). That's what PPM files are for.